# How do I check my own Baum Welch Algorithm

Tags: baum-welch

Given an observation {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0}

Transition matrix$\,$A
\begin{bmatrix}
    0.5 & 0.5 \\
    0.3 & 0.7 
\end{bmatrix}

Emission matrix$\,$B
\begin{bmatrix}
    0.3 & 0.7 \\
    0.8 & 0.2 
\end{bmatrix}

Initial distribution$\,$B
\begin{bmatrix}
    0.2 & 0.8 
\end{bmatrix}

After 600 iterations I have the following new distribution matrix$\:$A and matrix$\:$B:
matrix$\,$A
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0.2418 & 0.7581 
\end{bmatrix}

matrix$\,$B
\begin{bmatrix}
    0.1869 & 0.8130 \\
    0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}

Any Library or software can help me to check my own result because I am not sure if it is right

Answer (score 2):

A surprisingly powerful check on whether there is an issue with your mathematical derivation of the Baum-Welch algorithm; or whether there is a bug in your implementation, is *whether the log-likelihood monotonically increases during each iteration step of the algorithm.* If your log-likelihood monotonically increases then the Baum-Welch algorithm is working *as intended*. If the log-likelihood decreases at any point, then you *know with certainty* that there is an issue with either your derivations, or your implementation in code.

That being said, just because Baum-Welch is working as intended *may not necessarily mean that it is giving you the correct answer with respect to your own specific purposes.*

As an example, depending on the distributional forms involved in your model (which I assume is a hidden Markov model), you may find that Baum-Welch may be sensitive to initial parameter guesses and find local maxima instead of a global maximum. Meaning that if you start with different parameter initialisations you get different final answers.

Depending on your context, using a local maximum out of many local maxima may be fine. However, if you are trying to use Baum-Welch for maximum likelihood estimation in the presence of latent variables (i.e. for a hidden Markov model), for which you do need a global maximum rather than a local maximum; then simply running Baum-Welch, getting a local maximum and using that will not be sufficient. Why? Because maximum-likelihood estimation requires that the (log)-likelihood be maximised. If you find yourself in this situation, one "implementational hack" to deal with this is to use multiple initialisations.

A more comprehensive way to really know if Baum-Welch is working appropriately for toy examples is to assume "true parameters" which you fix in advance, and then use that to generate synthetic data. If Baum-Welch can recover your "true parameters", then you know it's working correctly.

Comment: Thank You in Advance